# placeholder text not showing in ie11

Tags: placeholder

why is my placeholder text not appearing for ie 11? This is the only ie I am using. It works fine on chrome and firefox.

```
<div class="leftform">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" name="EmailCheck" value="Email" class="checkboxSize">Email<br/>
        <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="Enter email address" class="textBox" size="35"><br>
        <input type="text" name="ConfirmEmail" placeholder="Confirm email address" class="textBox2" size="35"><br>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 hides the placeholder text when the input is in focus, which probably explains the confusion here (I just ran into this with an input we auto-focus).